# Unable to get simple countdown program to run

Tags: javascript

My Son is trying to get this code to work as he applying for College course. He neeeds to give an explanation of how it works from the Youtube example. The problem he has & I have is we cant get the code to run.

Youtube example he is working from.
**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_6CqjQ-L8Q&authuser=0**

This should be a simple countdown timer from 10 to zero - any ideas what I am doing wrong. Using Notepad++ to create the example & run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown(secs,elem)  {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
    if(secs<1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
    }   
    secs = secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">countdown(10,"status");</script>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `secs = secs--;`? Post decrement already mutates the value in place, but it evaluates to the previous value before decrementing...

Comment: So let me get this straight, your son might get into a college course not through his own effort but because of answers you get on StackOverflow?  Seems unethical to me

Comment: If the son was doing his own research I could understand ...

Comment: I think that this pretty much falls into the same category as a "Can you do my homework?" question.

Comment: @DBS I don't entirely agree, what if his son gets into the course not through his own effort but somebody else who actually tried got denied?

Comment: To be clear my Son is doing his own research and I have tried to help him with this post. Obviously you do not have children because if you did then helping them is a part of parenthood. It is very sad that you jump to conclusion straight away. But thankfully there are people on the forum wishing to help rather than just complain.

Comment: @user9377706 You know who's helping you: "karma whores" -- they don't care if the answer meets SO standards or might in some way be being used in an unethical manner, they just want the upvotes.  Let your son a) open his own account b) create his own posts and c) not bring getting into a college course into it -- it's this last point that makes it unethical in my opinion, that you son may be getting into a college course through Stack Overflow answers and denying somebody that did their own work.  In any case with a username like user1234567 I'm sure we won't be seeing you again any time soon

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- `secs = secs--` will not modify `secs`. Just `secs--` would be ok.
- The spelling of the function is not consistent

Some more issues, which are also present in the link you provided:

- When the timer is supposed to stop, the code still continues to call `setTimeout`
- This code uses a bad practice to pass a string to `setTimeout` while it is perfectly possible to pass a function.
- calling `clearTimeout` is useless where it happens, as at that moment there is no pending one.

Working code:

```js
function countdown(secs,elem)  {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    if(secs<1){
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>'
                          + '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
        return; // <---- don't call setTimeout again
    }   
    element.textContent = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
    // Spelling of countdown is important. Don't use string, but bind:
    setTimeout(countdown.bind(null, secs-1, elem), 1000);
}

countdown(10, 'status');
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and advice appreciated.